# Random list where each element differs by at most 1 from the previous element

Tags: haskell, random, monads, lazy-evaluation

I'm attempting to write a function which will generate a list, where the first element is specified as an argument to the function, and every element after that has a difference of at most 1 from the previous element. Here's what I have tried:

```
import Data.List
import System.Random

step :: Int -> IO Int
step n = (+n) <$> randomRIO (-1, 1)

steps :: Int -> Int -> IO [Int]
steps n = sequence . take n . iterate' (>>= step) . return
```

(I also tried with the non-strict `iterate` function, which gave me the same result).

The `step` function takes an integer and, at random, adds either -1, 0, or 1 to it. The `steps` function takes an amount of iterations to perform and a starting integer, and applies `step` the correct amount of times.

The problem is that `steps` gives me things like `[0,1,-1,0,1,1,1,3]`, which is wrong. It looks like each element is generated from scratch each time, whereas I want each element to depend on the previous one. This is the reason I decided to use `iterate'` instead of `iterate`, which says it reduces each iteration to WHNF before continuing, but even still it doesn't work.

Then I realised that the problem might arise from the fact that it will actually generate a list which looks something like:

```
[ n,
  n >>= step,
  n >>= step >>= step
  ... ]
```

And then it seems clear why it happens. So my question is, can I prevent this? Can I force Haskell to evaluate each element as it goes along? Is there a strict version of the `>>=` operator?

(Edit: I thought it might be useful to give an example of the kind of list I'm looking for, instead of just describing one. `[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1]`, for example)

Comment: As you may know what you're trying to do is usually called a "random walk"

Comment: Ah, I knew there was a term for it - just couldn't remember the name!

Comment: This remark reflects a misunderstanding: "This is the reason I decided to use `iterate'` instead of `iterate`, which says it reduces each iteration to WHNF before continuing, but even still it doesn't work." Strictness vs laziness doesn't change the result unless one option fails to terminate. If you're getting an *incorrect* result, you need to look at changing your algorithm, not adding strictness. Worrying about strictness in Haskell is mostly a performance concern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a strict version of the `>>=`. You need a monadic variant for `iterate`. After all, you already identified your problem, you're building an infinite number of *computations*:

```
[ return x , return x >>= step, return x >>= step >>= step, ... ]
```

You would need a monadic variant of `iterate`:

```
-- This function does not work, but shows the principle we would
-- want from such a function.
iterateM :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> m [a]
iterateM f x = do
     y  <- f x
     ys <- iterateM f y -- << this never terminates
     return (y:ys)
```

However, that variant does not exist*, as it will not terminate, for the same reasons that `forM [1..] return` does not terminate. We can, however, fix this, if change the algorithm to *first* generate the differences with `replicateM` and then *sum* those differences with `scanl`:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import System.Random (randomRIO)

step :: IO Int
step = randomRIO (-1, 1)

steps :: Int -> Int -> IO [Int]
steps n x = scanl (+) x <$> replicateM n step
```

In this case, we have a limited number of `step`s in `IO` and use the usual `scanl` to generate your desired list.

<sup>* There are some variants in streaming libraries where the *consumer* can decide whether a computation can run. `iterateM` can be implemented there, for example in `ConduitM`.</sup>